# QTextStream for printing both english and Unicode 16

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I ma having std::string in linux which is having both english and chinese character, when I write it into file I am able to write only english and chinese characters are coming as unknown character.

How can I print both english and chinese using QTextStream

I used setCodec("UTF-16") but after that all characters corrupted

```
  if( (lmxErr == lmx::elmx_error::ELMX_OK) && outFile.open( QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate ) ){
    QTextStream outStream( &outFile );
    outStream.setCodec("UTF-16");
    outStream << marshallingBuffer.c_str();
    outStream.flush();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do this

```
outStream << QString::fromStdString( marshallingBuffer );
```

instead of

```
outStream << marshallingBuffer.c_str();
```

Let's see what's going on, there. Say you have a single CJK character and store it in a `std::string` using a literal, this way:

```
std::string text = "其";
```

If you check the string size, surprisingly:

```
qDebug() << text.size(); //3 bytes
```

The utf-8 editor coded the character in three bytes, all stored in the string. Let's see them:

```
qDebug() << QByteArray(text.c_str(), text.size()).toHex(); //e585b6
```

Now into a stream, using a 16-bit Unicode codec:

```
QByteArray bytes;

QTextStream stream(&bytes, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream.setCodec("UTF-16");
stream << text.c_str();
stream.flush();

qDebug() << bytes.toHex(); //e5008500b600
```

You can see that every byte in the original string has been re-encoded into a 16-bit Unicode character, thus ending up in three non-printable characters.

Converting to `QString` will fix things up:

```
QString unicode = QString::fromStdString(text);
qDebug() << unicode.size(); //1 character, 2 bytes wide
```

this can be ouputted to the stream:

```
QByteArray bytes;

QTextStream stream(&bytes, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream.setCodec("UTF-16");
stream << unicode;
stream.flush();

qDebug() << bytes.toHex(); //7651 => U+5176 => 其
```

Comment: UTF 16 not working but UTF 8 working, why like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry that I'm not sure about the effectiveness of my solution. However, you may replace `outFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate)` with `outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)`.

Regards,